# Autohotkey: Remove ALL single characters from a string

Tags: autohotkey

I would like a AHK script, which removes all the single characters from a string/clipboard.

For instance I would like:

**A man went to a casino**

To become:

**man went to casino**

I have tried using RegEx & StringReplace but cannot create a script which does this.

Comment: What is the question? Did RegExReplace work for you? (see https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExReplace.htm )

Comment: Hi enkryptor. I didnt realise exactly which commands I needed and thus couldn't quite do it myself. But wOxxOm's solution has worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a non-space character `\S`, which is at a word boundary from both sides `\b`, trim spaces `\s+`:

```
s := regexreplace("A man went to a casino", "\b\S\b\s+", "")
```

Result:

> man went to casino

Comment: Thank you very much! That has worked perfectly. Also I modified it for my clipboard as follows (in case anyone needs it): clipboard := RegExReplace(clipboard, "\b\S\b\s+", "")